# How to get single output of Multiple select statement while scheduling SQL job

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table of employee where the `employee ID` first 4 fields are fixed but post that it changes based on location. I need to get report to find latest record from this table for all 3 location.
I am trying to run 3 select statement and when schedule a job, the output of `.csv file` has blank lines and `some ------  lines` .
can someone help if i can get the result in single file without any line-space.

```
select top1 from Employee where ID like '42345%'  Orderby JoinedDate Desc
select top1 from Employee where ID like '42346%'  Orderby JoinedDate Desc
select top1 from Employee where ID like '42347%'  Orderby JoinedDate Desc
```

Comment: Look into `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to write something like this:

```
select e.*
from ((select top 1 e.*
       from Employee e
       where ID like '42345%' 
       Orderby JoinedDate Desc
      ) union all
      (select top 1 e.*
       from Employee e
       where ID like '42346%' 
       Orderby JoinedDate Desc
      ) union all
      (select top 1 e.*
       from Employee e
       where ID like '42347%' 
       Orderby JoinedDate Desc
      ) union all
     ) e;
```

Perhaps a simpler way to write this uses `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(id, 5) order by joineddate desc) as seqnum
      from employee e
      where id like '4234[567]%'
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```